# Grok pattern matches but result also contains pattern

Tags: regex, xml, grok

I'm using [HerokuApp](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to create a reg_exp that matches the content of xml.

I'm not trying to parse xml but only to extract it.

```
<xml> <balise1> </balise1> <table> <tr> <td> cas1 </td> <td> cas2 </td> </tr> <tr> <td> new </td> <td> line </td> </tr> </table> </xml>
```

This is the pattern I wrote to match the content of tr tags. [Thanks to this documentation](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt)

```
(?<content>(<tr>(.)*</tr>))
```

So, the output of this regular expression gives :

```
{
  "content": [
    [
      "<tr> <td> cas1 </td> <td> cas2 </td> </tr> <tr> <td> new </td> <td> line </td> </tr>"
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I want it to be :

```
{
  "content": [
    [
      "<tr> <td> cas1 </td> <td> cas2 </td> </tr>"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The problem seems to be that the first occurrence is not detected and only the last occurrence is.

How can I specify that "any number of char" must not contain a new tr tag ?

Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: This should do the trick `(?<content>(<tr>(.)*?</tr>))` -  non-greedy matching after the opening tr tag.

Comment: Thanks for that ! Now I figured this wasn't the output I wanted. What if I want the output to be the list of all the <tr></tr> and not just the first one ? (if you post as an answer I'll accept it)

Comment: I edited the output I wanted. I actually want to list all occurrences of a tr balisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Collapsar comment, I used a greedy operator where I should have used a reluctant operator. [This document explains the syntax of operators](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE)

EDIT : I updated the link to the documentation as it was changed since.